# Eager/Lazy loaded member always empty with JPA one-to-many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, lazy-loading

I have two entities, a User and Role with a one-to-many relationship from user to role.  Here's what the tables look like:

```
mysql> select * from User;
+----+-------+----------+
| id | name  | password |
+----+-------+----------+
|  1 | admin | admin    |
+----+-------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from Role;
+----+----------------------+---------------+----------------+
| id | description          | name          | summary        |
+----+----------------------+---------------+----------------+
|  1 | administrator's role | administrator | Administration |
|  2 | editor's role        | editor        | Editing        |
+----+----------------------+---------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And here's the join table that was  created:

```
mysql> select * from User_Role;
+---------+----------+
| User_id | roles_id |
+---------+----------+
|       1 |        1 |
|       1 |        2 |
+---------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And here's the subset of `orm.xml` that defines the tables and relationships:

```
<entity class="User" name="User">
    <table name="User" />
    <attributes>
        <id name="id">
            <generated-value strategy="AUTO" />
        </id>
        <basic name="name">
            <column name="name" length="100" unique="true" nullable="false"/>
        </basic>
        <basic name="password">
            <column length="255" nullable="false" />
        </basic>
        <one-to-many
            name="roles"
            fetch="EAGER"
            target-entity="Role"
            />
    </attributes>
</entity>

<entity class="Role" name="Role">
    <table name="Role" />
    <attributes>
        <id name="id">
            <generated-value strategy="AUTO"/>
        </id>
        <basic name="name">
            <column name="name" length="40" unique="true" nullable="false"/>
        </basic>
        <basic name="summary">
            <column name="summary" length="100" nullable="false"/>
        </basic>
        <basic name="description">
            <column name="description" length="255"/>
        </basic>
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

Yet, despite that, when I retrieve the admin user, I get back an empty collection.  I'm using Hibernate as my JPA provider and it shows the following debug SQL:

```
select
    user0_.id as id8_,
    user0_.name as name8_,
    user0_.password as password8_ 
from
    User user0_ 
where
    user0_.name=? limit ?
```

When the one-to-many mapping is lazy loaded, that's the only query that's made.  This correctly retrieves the one admin user.  I changed the relationship to use eager loading and then the following query is made in addition to the above:

```
select
    roles0_.User_id as User1_1_,
    roles0_.roles_id as roles2_1_,
    role1_.id as id9_0_,
    role1_.description as descript2_9_0_,
    role1_.name as name9_0_,
    role1_.summary as summary9_0_ 
from
    User_Role roles0_ 
left outer join
    Role role1_ 
        on roles0_.roles_id=role1_.id 
where
    roles0_.User_id=?
```

Which results in the following results:

```
+----------+-----------+--------+----------------------+---------------+----------------+
| User1_1_ | roles2_1_ | id9_0_ | descript2_9_0_       | name9_0_      | summary9_0_    |
+----------+-----------+--------+----------------------+---------------+----------------+
|        1 |         1 |      1 | administrator's role | administrator | Administration |
|        1 |         2 |      2 | editor's role        | editor        | Editing        |
+----------+-----------+--------+----------------------+---------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Hibernate obviously knows about the roles, yet `getRoles()` still returns an empty collection. Hibernate also recognized the relationship sufficiently to put the data in the first place.

What problems can cause these symptoms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, there is some kind of mismatch between your physical model and the mapping of your entities: the physical model implements a many-to-many relation (with a join table) while the mapping declares a one-to-many relation. IMO, the physical model is "right": one User can have many Roles, one Role can be associated to many Users. In other words, the relation between User and Roles is a many-to-many.

Comment: Good point about the many-to-many relationship.  It hadn't crossed my mind since I didn't yet need data from the other direction, but it is true.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a couple of different symptoms that cause the problem:

1. *User error*.  In this case, I was in error and everything I had above was working correctly.  I made a dumb, (ok... really dumb) mistake.
2. *Schema changes*.  In switching between one-to-many and many-to-many relationships, the schema was updated but my data wasn't repopulated.  Since the data wasn't repopulated, a third column in the join table was NULL and unused resulting in zero records returned.

The many-to-many mapping also works.  Here's what it ended up looking like:

```
<entity class="User" name="User">
    <table name="User" />
    <attributes>
        <id name="id">
            <generated-value strategy="AUTO" />
        </id>
        <basic name="name">
            <column name="name" length="100" unique="true" nullable="false"/>
        </basic>
        <basic name="password">
            <column length="255" nullable="false" />
        </basic>
        <many-to-many
            name="roles"
            fetch="EAGER"
            target-entity="Role"
            />
    </attributes>
</entity>

<entity class="Role" name="Role">
    <table name="Role" />
    <attributes>
        <id name="id">
            <generated-value strategy="AUTO"/>
        </id>
        <basic name="name">
            <column name="name" length="40" unique="true" nullable="false"/>
        </basic>
        <basic name="summary">
            <column name="summary" length="100" nullable="false"/>
        </basic>
        <basic name="description">
            <column name="description" length="255"/>
        </basic>
        <many-to-many
            name="users"
            mapped-by="roles"
            />
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

It turns out that either solution works, but the many-to-many solution assumes that I have a field within my role object that allows me to query (and/or set) the users.  This will make role management easier.